# How to make join between two entities, if entity framework doesn't map the junction entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

I have a many to many relationiship, but as I'm using EF, I don't have the junction table, because it doesn't have a primary key.

Usually, if TableAB had a primary key, I'd make it like this:

```
var query = from a in db.TableA
            join ab in db.TableAB on
            a.Id equals ab.Id_TableA
            join b in db.TableB on
            ab.Id_TableB equals b.Id
            select { a.Field, b.Field };
```

But, as I don't have mapped the TableAB, what is the correct way to do the JOIN?

I've already created the navigation properties, using API fluent mapping. But using navigation properties to get data, the performance it's worse, or not?

Edit: I'm using POCO.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood from question, your TableAB has composite primary key [id_TableA, id_TableB]. So I think that it's better to make a correct mapping of this key. It should look something like that:

```
public class TableAB
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [ForeignKey("TableA")]
    public int id_TableA { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("TableB")]
    public int id_TableB{ get; set; }
```

}

Comment: Set these two properties as "key" works, but these properties aren't a composite key, they are only foreign keys. In this case, the correct is to create in the junction table a composite key?

Comment: Yes it should be a composite primary key, as for classical definition of junction table and if you don't have exigence not to do that.